# How to get all subclass of a given class in a directory with Python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-module

**I want a list of subclass object, but not just their names.**

I figure it like this:

- firstly, use `os.walk` to get all `.py` files
- then use `imp` module to import all of those files ( **<- this performs bad**)
- check whether those classes is the subclasses

the directory structure:

```
├── src
│   ├── __init__.py 
│   └── connector.py
└── test_app
    ├── __init__.py
    └── test.py
```

`connector.py` code:

```
import imp


class BaseModel(object):
    """which I wanna check it's subclass"""


class SomeClass(object):
    @classmethod
    def detect_all(cls, app_path=None):
        for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(app_path):
            for name in files:
                file_list.append(os.path.join(path, name)) if name.endswith('.py') and not name.startswith('_') else ''
        for file in file_list:
            imp.load_source(file.split('/')[0], file)
        print(cls.get_all_subclasses(BaseModel))

    @staticmethod
    def get_all_subclasses(cls):
        # argument cls is a target class
        all_subclasses = []

        for subclass in cls.__subclasses__():
            all_subclasses.append(subclass)
            all_subclasses.extend(SomeClass.get_all_subclasses(subclass))
```

`test.py` code:

```
import os
import sys
sys.path.append('../')
sys.path.append('../src')

from src.connector import SomeClass, BaseModel

class User(BaseModel):
    pass

b = User()

current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

print(SomeClass.detect_all(current_dir))
```

but when I run this file, the result is always loop, and finally gives me a `RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

How to meet my need, or how to fix this code.

Answer (score 2):

First: Python is not Java.  Delete the useless SomeClass class and let the two functions just be functions in the module.  While doing so, remove the useless 'cls' parameter of detect_all.  My answer below assumes this change.

The code posted will not run because the initialization `file_list = []` is missing.  I assume it was there when running.

I believe the infinite recursion comes about as follows: `test.py` calls `detect_all(current_dir)`.  `current_dir` calls `os.walk(current_dir)`, which returns `'test.py'`.  It then calls `imp.load_source('test.py')`.  `test.py` then (re)calls `detect_all(current_dir)`.  And so on.

`imp` had been deprecated in favor of `importlib`.  The currect `imp` chapter does not mention `load_source`, but I presume that it does *not* add `'test'` to `sys.modules` before loading the source.  Normal imports avoid infinite recursion by checking `sys.modules` first and only loading a module not already there and only after first adding an empty module to sys.modules.

What you should do: when you run test.py, '', representing directory `test_app/`, is prepended to sys.path.  So you can import modules in that directory by module name. Make a list of `mod_names` of module names. When os.walk finds `'xyz.py'`, strip the .py extension.  When recursing in subdirs, prepend `'subname.'` so you get a proper dotted module name such as you would use in a normal import statement.  Then replace the imp loop with

```
    for mod in mod_names:
        importlib.import_module(mod)
```

I do something similar to test all the modules in a package I am writing.  I avoid recursion with an exclude list (that contains a few other modules also).  However, this should not be needed as import_module does add entries to sys.modules.

Comment: Thank you. But I don't know the mod_names and how many they are, so i cant provide a module names list at the beginning and this is what i want to achieve

Comment: You still use os.walk and get the module names from the file names after removing '.py'.  You also have to use subdirectory names.